# Design to support a fast and slow client

Tags: software-design

I have a situation where I host a high RPS highly available service that receives requests aka commands. These commands have to be sent to N downstream clients, who actually execute them. Each downstream client is separate microsevice and has different constraints like mode (sync,async), execution cadence etc.

Should a slow downstream client build the logic to receive all requests and execute them in batches as they want ? Or my service should build logic to talk to slow and fast clients by maintaining state for commands across downstream clients. Share your opinions

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to give any prescriptive advice, but I'd start with dividing the tasks into async and sync first. Those are 2 completely different workloads that, most likely, would require different implementation stacks. I'll give you an idea of what you can start with in the world of AWS...

Not knowing what you mean by async, I'd default to a message-bus setup. In that case you can use something like Amazon Kinesis or Kafka for ingestion purposes, and kicking off Lambda or EC2 instance. If the clients need to be notified of a finished job they can either long-poll an SQS queue, subscribe to an SNS topic, or use [MQTT with websockets](https://aws.amazon.com/iot/) for a long-running connection.

The sync tasks are easier, since it's all about processing power. Just make sure you have your EC2 instances in an auto-scaling group behind an ALB or API Gateway to scale out, and in, appropriately.

This is a very simple answer since I don't have any details needed to be more precise, but this should give you an idea of where to get started.